# "Fare" o "lasciare" come traduzione di "let"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Ho visto che l'inglese *let* si traduce spesso con il verbo *fare*:

- Come on, **let** me see! = Ma dai, **fammi** vedere!
- **Let** me know if you need anything = **Fammi** sapere se hai bisogno di qualcosa

Di solito traduco *let* come *lasciare*, ma mi sa che in questo caso *lasciare* non va. Dall'altra parte, secondo il [*Corriere della sera*](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/L/lasciare.shtml?refresh_ce-cp) anche *lasciare* andrebbe bene:

> **II.Seguito dall'inf.** di un v., *lasciare* assume valore causativo, nei sign. di permettere ad altri di fare qlco., produrre certi effetti: *l. partire il figlio; lasciami lavorare!.* Oltre che dall'infinito, può essere seguito da frase (introd. da *che*): *lascia che decida da solo* (...).

Tutti i tre esempi riportati dal Corriere si possono costruire con *let*:

- **Lasciare** partire qualcuno = **Let** someone go.
- **Lasciami** lavorare! = **Let** me work!
- **Lascia** che decida da solo = **Let** him decide for himself.

Quindi la mia domanda è: Le versioni di sopra sono le uniche possibilità, o si può anche dire...?

- Ma dai, **lasciami** vedere.
- **Lasciami** sapere se...
- **Fare** partire qualcuno.
- **Fammi** lavorare!
- **Fai** che decida da solo.

Non sono sicura se queste frasi siano ben formate (sopratutto le tre ultime). Se non lo sono: **Come decidere tra *fare* e *lasciare*?**

Comment: *Lasciami sapere* è, diciamo, insolito. `;-)` Al contrario, “lasciami lavorare!” è meglio di “fammi lavorare” che ha un significato diverso.

Answer (score 5):

C'è una differenza sostanziale fra *lasciare* e *fare* in questi contesti che invece il verbo inglese *let* non distingue.

Si dice *fammi sapere se hai bisogno di qualcosa* perché si richiede un'azione specifica dell'interlocutore. Una costruzione come *lasciami sapere* non ha molto senso.

Si può dire *lasciami detto se hai bisogno di qualcosa*, intendendo che l'interlocutore mandi una comunicazione di qualche genere, orale o scritta; ma, in questo caso, l'inglese non userebbe *let*, bensì *leave* (*leave me a note if you need something*).

Al contrario, *lasciami lavorare* richiede una “non azione” dell'interlocutore, cioè che la smetta di intralciarmi. L'esortazione *fammi lavorare* è la richiesta che l'interlocutore mi procuri un lavoro. Si può anche dire *fammi lavorare* in questo contesto, purché il tono sia diverso: *ma fammi lavorare!*

Tradurre *let* con *lasciare* è spesso sbagliato: in molti casi è *permettere*. Una frase come *let me see* può anche essere resa con *lasciami guardare*, nel senso di *permettimi di guardare*; il contesto inglese dovrebbe chiarire la situazione. Per esempio, il mio interlocutore sta guardando dal buco della serratura: *lasciami guardare* potrebbe andar bene, nel senso di *togliti di lì e fa' guardare anche me*. Certamente, anche *fammi guardare* andrebbe bene.

Per concludere: in questi casi, con *fare* rischi meno di sbagliare.

Comment: Grazie! Quello che non capisco è perché si usa "fare" in "fa' guardare anche me" se questa è anche una "non azione". A mio parere, il senso di "smetterla" in "lasciami lavorare" è più o meno equivalente a quello di "togliersi" in "fammi guardare", e nonostante non si dice "fammi lavorare" (intendendo "lasciami lavorare"). "Fare" è sinonimo di "permettere (di)" in "fammi guardare/entrare/uscire/salire/ecc", ma non in "fammi lavorare", anche se "lasciami lavorare" significa giustamente "permettimi di lavorare"(+)

Comment: (+) Non so se mi sono spiegata, ma basicamente sto cercando di capire quando "fare" si può usare come sinonimo di "lasciare/permettere (di)".

Comment: _fammi guardare_ potrebbe richiedere una azione, per es. spostarsi.

Comment: @mario Infatti, ricade nel caso di “fammi sapere”, sebbene non ci sia molta differenza con “lasciami guardare”. In definitiva, “fammi…”  è più sicuro di “lasciami…”, dal punto di vista del principiante.